# Why is my Brick texture warping so many different ways?

Tags: texturing, uv, shader-nodes

I've tried unwrapping the UV's employing various methods. I've tried using a mapping node. I'm at a loss how to get this texture to just look like uniform bricks in every direction.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awyzyo4boxgx1a8/Brick%20Tex%20How.blend?dl=0)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Moonboots has the answer for you, but any particular reason why you've used a solidify modifier in the first place rather than simply insetting the top face of the cube and extruding it downwards? That would making it much easier to mark any seams and UV unwrap it.

Comment: @JohnEason I'm sure it would, and I seriously need to learn more about UV wrapping because I don't even know how to use seams and such.  I've been placing my main focus in Blender in other areas like lighting and geometry nodes, but I badly need to enhance my knowledge about using UV's.  The reason I used solidify is because while I'm designing I like to keep things as dynamic as possible so I can quickly make broad changes as I go.  Also a case for Geonodes, which I'm in love with.

Comment: Fair enough, but as @Moonboots says you have to apply the modifi8er before you can expect UV unwrapping and textures to work correctly. There are hundreds of unwrapping tutorials online. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM) is the official Blender one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate* but for the moment your UVs are heteregoneous and stretched. Maybe first apply the *Solidify* modifier, then uwrap again, as your object is perpendicular, use for example the *Cube Projection* option, and you'll get something correct:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. It was applying the Solidify modifier that clinched it- I totally forgot you can't use that and maintain very accurate UV coords.